# Alarm manager Android

Tags: java, android

Привет. Мое приложение должно периодически проигрывать короткий аудиофайл.
Реализовал это с помощью `AlarmManager` и `BroadcastReceiver`.

Вот код.
Main Activity.java :

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Context context = (Context) getApplicationContext();

    int interval = 10000;


    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShortTimeEntryReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, alarmIntent );

}
```

ShortTimeEntryReceiver.java:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.subhanallah);
    mp.start();
}
```

Проблема в том, что файл начинает проигрываться сразу после запуска приложения, в остальном все нормально, каждые 10 секунд он повторяет воспроизведение.
Подскажите что я делаю неправильно? Как убрать воспроизведение при запуске?

Answer (score 4):

Вот в этой строчке проблема.

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, alarmIntent );
```

Второй параметр отвечает за время когда будет вызван onReceive. Думаю что то вроде этого должно помочь.

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis()+interval, interval, alarmIntent );
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!))Помогло!